# i couldn't print the value for slider range,what i 've to do?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I couldn't print the value for slider range, what I 've to do? 
this is my code

```
<?php
                        $salary=array(
                            'type'=>'range',
                            'name'=>'salary',
                            'id'=>'salary',
                            'class'=>'slider tags',
                            'value'=>'',
                            'data-slider-min'=>1,
                            'data-slider-max'=>30,
                            'data-slider-step'=>1,
                            'data-slider-value'=>'[1,1]',
                            'rules'=>'required');
                      echo form_input($salary); ?>
```

Comment: if(hasError!==true){ 
should be if($hasError!==true){

Comment: Proper indentation of code would make things a lot easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF]; ?>" novalidate>

<?php
if($sent===true){
echo "<h2 class='success'>Thanks, your message has been sent successfully</h2>";  //Line 117
```

You missed a `'` after `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF` – and therefor your text literal only ends when the next `'` is encountered, that is after `echo "<h2 class=` – and after that follows `success`, which is not a valid PHP expression and therefor throws that error.

In an editor with proper syntax highlighting, you should have been able to spot this very quickly – so get one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(hasError!==true){
```

should be

```
if($hasError!==true){
```